# cambiar el botón de retorno de la toolbar

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al cambiar de icono de la toolbar el de retorno por una x lo intente si lo cambia pero el tamaño no es lo esperado.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp);
```

Sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que sea de tamaño normal le pongo un poco mas pequeño pero me sale todo pixeleado, hay una forma de ponerlo normal o por defecto pero que sea un botón clear o cancel como una x.

Comment: Gunnar, sería buena idea que agregaras tu Layout, usas FrameLayout para contener el boton?0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La medida debe ser por guideline  24dp asegura tener esa medida y puedes usar la propiedad **android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"** en tu toolbar para hacer de tamaño adecuado el icono.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Preguntaba si usabas un FrameLayout para contener el boton, si es así puedes usar la propiedad:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```